# How can I calculate the "wasted" force in a rotation-to-occillation piston?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, oscillators

A piston doesn't change its angle when its connecting rod's angle is changed from the pulling/pushing of the wheel/crankshaft because it needs to be inside of a constraint (a cylinder or track to hold it straight). Because it's being held by those constraints, there must be a considerable amount of side to side force used against the constraint. I'm wondering if there's any way of calculating the amount of useless force in the piston, specifically the force that doesn't contribute to its up and down motion, based on the force put into the rotating motion.

Comment: You might be able to calculate the sideways force involved for some specific geometries and situations, but I don't understand the "wasted" part.  There's no "conservation of force", so you don't necessarily lose efficiency just because a sideways force exists.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I don't know if I've explained this right. Basically I'm talking about the force from the crank/connecting rod that is pushing the piston into the side of the cylinder/track. What I mean by "wasted" is that a lot of force from the rotation isn't converted into oscillatory force because the piston has to be held so that it always faces the same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to calculate the piston side forces?

- Like any other problem in mechanics, start with a sketch of the problem with all relevant dimensions. Add the driving degrees of freedom that completely describe the state of the system.  For example the crank angle.
- Split each part into its own free body diagram and describe the applied forces as well as the connection reaction forces. For example, the piston has gas forces acting downwards that are derived from the cylinder pressures.

[image: Single Piston System]

- Derive analytical expressions for the kinematics of the parts, as well as all the motions of the centers of mass in terms of the degrees of freedom. For example, the connecting rod angle $\beta$ is found from the crank angle $\varphi$ by describing the horizontal position of the wristpin

  $$ \text{(crank)} \sin \varphi - \text{(conrod)} \sin \beta = \text{(offset)} $$
- Take time derivative of the kinematics, noting that $\dot{\varphi} = \Omega$ is constant, but $\dot{\beta}$ isn't.
- Describe the acceleration of each center of mass, as well as the rotational acceleration of each body. For example the rotational acceleration of the conrod is $$ \alpha_{\rm conrod} = \ddot{\beta} $$
- Define the equations of motion. There are three equations for each part (two for the center of mass, and one for rotation) and three parts total. A total of 9 equations is produced.
- Count your unknown force variables. Each pin has two forces, the piston has a side load as well as a restoring moment, and the crankshaft has a reaction torque needed to keep the crank speed constant. This means there are 3*2+2+1 = 9 unknowns.
- Solve the system of 9 equations for the 9 unknowns. The system of equations is linear so you can solve it numerically, or analytically or by elimination or ...
- Profit!

Answer (score 1):

You can waste energy and power and other things, but you can't really waste force.  We don't have a fixed supply of force that runs low.

Energy transfers when you apply a force over a distance.  If you apply a force and there's no movement, then no energy is required.

In your example of a piston converting rotational to oscillatory motion, there are several places where you can lose power.  The piston could fit sloppily inside the cylinder and rattle.  The connecting arm could have loose joints.  Burrs in the joints could catch and cause damage.

But you don't get a direct loss just because the force is not in line with the piston travel.  As long as the friction losses are kept low, only the longitudinal component of the force is doing any work and consuming energy.

If you want to reduce this sideways force, there are engineering benefits.  You might end up reducing wear, allowing it to be made of weaker materials, or lowering losses due to friction and other things.  But if the friction losses are already low, then you won't get any extra power delivered by making that change.

So for that reason, I wouldn't use the term "wasted" here.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little wasted energy from the kinetic friction of the piston to the  polished, lubricated cylinder walls, due to the angle of the connecting rod. The rod is straight with the cylinder at the top and bottom of the stroke, and approaches the maximum angle at mid stroke. Most pistons designed for engine longevity, have skirts in line with the crankshaft rotation,  to decrease piston rattle and spread the sideways push over a larger area. A longer rod, with the piston and cylinder farther from the crankshaft would decrease this angle, but a heavier rod would also increase waste energy. High performance engines usually have as short a rod as possible, some high performance pistons are even very short, with no skirts, to make the rod even shorter.

Comment: About 25% of efficiency losses on a modern combustion engine is due to friction on the piston skirts. So piston side loads are a _major_ contributor to wasted energy,